# How to apply CSS elements property on multiple ids or class

Tags: css, styles

i try to apply CSS  property **option:disabled** on multiple ids but its only apply on last ID 
I try both way

```
select#id1, #id2, #id3 , #id4,#id5  option:disabled{
    color: #333336;
}

select#id1, #id2, #id3 , #id4,#id5 >  option:disabled{
    color: #333336;
}
```

but it not apply on all ids

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first 4 rules select only the elements with id's #id1, #id2 etc.
Each comma separated part in the selector is a selector independent of other selector segments. So, you cannot use first selector as basis for following selectors.

```
select#id1  option:disabled, 
#id2  option:disabled,
#id3  option:disabled,
#id4  option:disabled,
#id5  option:disabled{

}
```

In plain css, I don't think you can avoid specifying `option:disabled` multiple times (except using class instead of id). You can give your select elements a common class e.g. `myselect`, and then write a single rule instead of this, like -

```
.myselect option:disabled{
}
```

Comment: Sir @MOHIT I try to avoid 

    select#id1 option:disabled, #id2 option:disabled, #id3 option:disabled

Comment: is there any way without 
#id2  option:disabled,#id3  option:disabled,

Comment: @MohammadAhmadShabbir you are using css or any preprocessor like less, sass etc. ?

Comment: Sir I Am Using CSS

Comment: @MohammadAhmadShabbir I have updated my answer to use class instead of id. Please check if this fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Sir I thinks so  IN MY CASE it is not possible with CSS actually  i have 6 different drop down (select ) so I highly  appreciated for your time and use your first answer